# Cursors in LIMIT clause for Google Cloud Datastore GQL queries

Tags: python, gql, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use a cursor in my GQL query. According to [Google Cloud Datastore grammar](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql_reference#grammar) and a following example, I could do something like this:

```
people = Person.all().filter("age >", 18)
start_cursor = memcache.get('person_start_cursor')

if start_cursor:
   people.with_cursor(start_cursor)

query_people = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age < 65 LIMIT @start_cursor 2")

for person in query_people:
      self.response.out.write('<p><b>Name:</b> %s ' % person.name)
```

I obtain the error: "BadQueryError: Parse Error: Non-number limit in LIMIT clause at symbol @start_cursor". What I'm doing wrong? The cursor is not well defined? I've followed [this steps](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Query_cursors)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the python db's version of GQL (reference found [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference)) which has not yet been updated to support the new features found in the Google Cloud Datastore GQL (reference found [here](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference))

In the python's db module, a start cursor can be set using the `with_cursor` function:

```
query_people.with_cursor(start_cursor)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Alfred, but the grammar that I want use is for Google Cloud Datastore, not for Google App Engine (your first reference). BTW, Where it's say that the grammar has not been updated?

Comment: Your code is using the App Engine db API. Are you running your code in  App Engine under the App you are trying to query?

Comment: Yes, I see... I was wrong, I've mixed concepts. I thought that I could use in App Engine db API, GQL for Google Datastore... I would like use GQL for Google Datastore, so I following this steps [link](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_a_new_cloud_project). Because it's not possible use it in App Engine db isn't it? Sorry for the error, thanks

Comment: We are working on allowing db and ndb to work on top of the Google Cloud Datastore API, but it does not currently.